# How do I create hash key in node js fort payumoney payment gateway integration?

Tags: node.js, hash, payumoney

How do I create hash key in node js for payumoney payment gateway integration?
I installed

> npm install sha512

Script I used:

```
var txnid = buffer.toString('hex').toUpperCase();
var string = marchentKey + '|' + txnid + '|' + amount + '|' + productinfo + '|' + firstname + '|' + email + '|' + udf1 + '|' + udf2 + '|||||||||' + salt;
var hash = sha512(string);
```

Gives error in angular js that key is not right.

Comment: One think I noticed that the form post values and hash key generation function used values should be same.

Answer (score 2):

`hash=sha512("key|5937f928cbb2a51c4fe8c4c1|10|Shopping|Test|test@test.com|||||||||||salt");
function sha512(str) {
  return crypto.createHash('sha512').update(str).digest('hex');
}`

Try this. replace your merchantId(key) and SALT in above string

Answer (score 1):

node already have crypto module so you dont need to install other module

```
var crypto=require('crypto');
var now= (new Date()).valueOf().toString();
var random = Math.random().toString();
crypto.createHash('sha1').update(now+ random).digest('hex'); //this is your unique hash
```

Comment: Thanks Anshuman! I need to create payumoney hash key using SALT and MERCHANT KEY

Comment: so instead of now and random ,you can use your own variable say salt and merchant key.

Answer (score 0):

**Generating hash for payuMoney from angular**

1) install `npm i js-sha512`

2) Import in component which you want to use

`import * as sha512 from 'js-sha512';`

3) use it in your function like below

`var hash = sha512.sha512('pass form data with |");`